# Can I get different configuration APKs for "raw folder" when using app-bundles?

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I'm planning to submit app-bundle instead of signed apks to playstores. I was able to create multiple configuration apks depending on screen density, locale and device configurations. 
The thing is I also have multiple .mp3 localized files inside "res/raw".

**I was wondering if there's a way (or a workaround) to create configuration apks for this also**? It'll decrease the apk size even more.

I can see from the google documentation [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/your-first-dynamic-app/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0) that *abi, density and language* are the only 3 properties.

```
android {
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = true
        }
        density {
            enableSplit = true
        }
        abi {
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }
}
```

If not, is there some timeline when this'll be available? (not the question to be asked here probably, mentioning it just in case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say *.mp3 localized files inside `res/raw`*, I'm assuming that you mean different files for different locales. But for this you've already enabled the split:

```
language {
    enableSplit = true
}
```

You only need to put the *raw* files in folder for the specific locales:

```
res/raw/file_en.mp3 → res/raw-en/file.mp3
res/raw/file_fr.mp3 → res/raw-fr/file.mp3
...
```